# Store sequences of data in sqllite3 (blob)

Tags: python, sqlite, blob

I want to store list-like objects in sqlite3.
I'm not interested in querying the content of the list, so a blob cell is fine.
After searching for different methods, I came up with using a struct. 
However, it doesn't work:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime   
import time 
import struct

# Create DB
dbpath = './test.db'
db = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""           
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trials (
    timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, emg BLOB) """)
cursor.execute ('DELETE FROM trials')
# Define vars
now = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = time.mktime(now.timetuple())
emg = range(200)
s = struct.pack('f'*len(emg), *emg)

# Store vars
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO trials VALUES (?,?)""", (timestamp,s))
db.commit()

# Fetch vars
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM trials WHERE timestamp = ?""", (timestamp,))
out = cursor.fetchone()
s1 = out[1] 
print(s1) # --> EMPTY 
emg1=struct.unpack('f'*(len(s1)/4), s1)
print(emg1) # -->()

# However
emg0=struct.unpack('f'*(len(s)/4), s)
print(emg0) # --> (0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0....
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong, or recommendations on a better/more pythonish way to save long sequences of data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what isn't working for you specifically - I get the same output on Python 3 if I replace the division operators (/ with //).

However, maybe `pickle` is better-suited for your problem than struct? Here is your code modified to use it. The last line checks to make sure the stored and retrieved value is the same as the original value.
    import sqlite3
    import datetime
    import time 
    import pickle

```
# Create DB
dbpath = './test.db'
db = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""           
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trials (
    timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, emg BLOB) """)
cursor.execute ('DELETE FROM trials')
# Define vars
now = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = time.mktime(now.timetuple())
emg = list(range(200))
s = pickle.dumps(emg, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Store vars
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO trials VALUES (?,?)""", (timestamp,s))
db.commit()

# Fetch vars
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM trials WHERE timestamp = ?""", (timestamp,))
out = cursor.fetchone()
s1 = out[1] 
emg1 = pickle.loads(s1)

# Test equality
print(emg1 == emg)
```

Comment: Pickle works definetly better for me, since it allows to store also different types of objects with no change in the code! Thanks!